# Access private function of a RequireJS module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have this module:

```
define(function() {
   clickHandlerA = function() { ... }
   clickHandlerB = function() { ... }

   return {
     handle : function(param) {
        doSomething(param);
        var handler = 'clickHandler' + param;
     }
   }
}
```

Now, I need to somehow call the appropriate click handler. I tried

```
if (typeof handler  == 'function') {
   handler.call();
}
```

I also tried

```
if (handler in this) {
   handler();
}
```

but none work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't access handler from outside, you have to export it.

Comment: @dystroy And if I were to transfer clickHandlerA and B to return statement of my module, how would I call them and check if they existed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand you need is this :

```
define(function() {
   var handlers = {
      A: function() { ... },
      B: function() { ... }
   };

   return {
     handle : function(param) {
        doSomething(param);
        return handlers[param];
     }
   }
}
```

So you may do this from outside

```
 yourModule.handle('A')();
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for.